# Windows 8 Loop Issue after disk partitioning

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Hi I have some issue with my recently bought (few hours!) laptop. My laptop is a Sony Vaio running a Windows 8 64 bit. It has over 600GB disk size that I immediately decided to partition it into two. I used the EaseUS Partition Master to perform this and select to reduce the size of the main partition and divide it into two. The application force the OS to restart in order to complete the operation and then it goes to the loop where we select language and keyboard layout and all those options for repairing.

Using Window's DiskPartition, this is what I get:

```
DISKPART> sel disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    673 GB  Healthy    
  Volume 2     D   Recovery     NTFS   Partition     23 GB  Healthy    
  Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition    260 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4         SONYSYS      NTFS   Partition    260 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 5         Windows RE   FAT32  Partition   1474 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

From what I've read so far, it seems that something is wrong with my C volume. Firstly it needs to be in FAT32 and then secondly, it needs to be bootable (hence the missing Boot in the info section).

Can someone guide me on what should I enter in the command prompt to get this fixed? Thanks!

Comment: no solutions at all? :(

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but I can point you away from a couple of blind alleys. First, the Windows `C:` partition should normally be NTFS, not FAT32. You're either thinking of *very* old versions of Windows or confusing the Windows `C:` partition with the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition), which should indeed be FAT32. Second, I'm not very familiar with the Windows DiskPartition tool, but EFI/GPT booting does *not* rely on a "boot flag" the way it's used on older BIOS/MBR boot systems.